# Why wcscmp() returns True when two strings are different?

Tags: c++

I am using `wcscmp()` to compare two unicode strings. They are different, but `wcscmp()` return true. I am using Visual Studio 2019.

[image: details as screenshot]

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{        
    auto ddd = L"HP 24f Display";
    auto eee = L"122fff";
    bool gggg = wcscmp(ddd, eee);
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Comment: Because wcscmp returns an int that is 0 if the two strings are equals http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcscmp/

Comment: @Nico238 ok,thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

The `wcscmp()` function returns an integer value, not a bool value. If the two strings are equal, it returns the integer value 0. If they are not equal, it returns a non-zero value indicating whether the first string is less than or greater than the second string.

Solution :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto ddd = L"122fff";
    auto eee = L"122fff";
    int gggg = wcscmp(ddd, eee);
    if (gggg != 0)
    {
        std::cout << " False" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << " True" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`wcscmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcscmp) returns an `int`, not a `bool`. Given your input, it returns a negative value.

When a non-zero `int` value is converted to `bool`, it becomes `true`.